Is this an unnamed function, struct method (?) or something else - function definition in Julia
I'm new to Julia and just trying to understand the following block of code. I know that @with_kw comes from the Parameters package and allows us to set default values for struct variables and what the purpose of the where keyword is. But I don't really get what is happening on the line after the struct declaration i.e.
BackTracking{TF}(args...; kwargs...) etc - are we modifying the struct's constructor, conflating the 'TF,Int' types and replacing them with just one type 'TF'?
I also don't understand the function definition below - what is the meaning of the first set of brackets? Is this function another constructor for the struct?
@with_kw struct BackTracking{TF, TI}
    iterations::TI = 1_000
    ρ_hi::TF = 0.5
    etc more varables
end

BackTracking{TF}(args...; kwargs...) where TF = BackTracking{TF,Int}(args...; kwargs...)

function (ls::BackTracking)(α_0::Tα = real(T)(1), etc more parameters) where {T, Tα}


    some stuff


    α_0 = min(α_0, min(alphamax, ls.maxstep / norm(s, Inf)))
    ls(ϕ, α_0, ϕ_0, dϕ_0)
end


This line
BackTracking{TF}(args...; kwargs...) where TF = BackTracking{TF,Int}(args...; kwargs...)

defines a new constructor method for the type BackTracking. It's using the short-form function definition syntax, and is equivalent to
function BackTracking{TF}(args...; kwargs...) where TF 
    return BackTracking{TF,Int}(args...; kwargs...)
end

As you can see, you only provide the first type parameter here, so in effect it says that if you don't provide the second type parameter, it will use Int for that parameter. In other words, writing BackTracking{Float64}(...) is equivalent to writing BackTracking{Float64, Int}(...).
The last function definition makes objects callable. If you create an object obj = BackTracking{Float64}(...), then you can treat obj as if it were a function, and call it like
obj(x)

